# Devolver la fecha en formato local

Tags: java

Quiero extraer la fecha actual de una forma en concreto y no encuentro la manera de hacerlo.

Verán lo que tengo es esto:

```
String data = LocalDate.now().toString();
```

Que te devuelve la fecha de esta forma:

```
2021-11-05
```

Pero mi intención es extraerla de esta forma y no encuentro la manera:

```
12 jul. 2021
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas hacer uso de [`LocalDate.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) con [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) o bien [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate-java.time.format.FormatStyle-):

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

class Pruebas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate hoy = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println(hoy.toString());
        System.out.println(hoy.format(
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy")
        ));
        System.out.println(hoy.format(
            DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
        ));
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
$ java Pruebas
2021-11-05
05 nov. 2021
5 nov. 2021
```